# The public subscriber lists pages not matching batch size and total counts

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a list of my public subscribers. When I execute the request below I get weird and inconsistent results. When I ask for a max result size of 50 I get two pages back, one with 27 and another with 9. Also when I look at my web page subscribers it says I only have 24 public subscribers. I have 95 total subscribers.

1. Why is it paging in buckets less than my max page size?
2. Why are the reported numbers so far off?

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&mySubscribers=true&key=[MY_API_KEY]](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&mySubscribers=true&key=%5BMY_API_KEY%5D)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mySubscribers), for to call the `Subscriptions.list` API endpoint with parameter `mySubscribers=true` you have to pass on to the endpoint proper authorization credentials:

> [**mySubscribers**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mySubscribers) (boolean)
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to `true` to retrieve a feed of the subscribers of the authenticated user in no particular order.

Therefore, passing on only an application key, via the parameter `key`, is not sufficient. If passing on proper authorization credentials (i.e. a valid access token), then the `key` parameter is superfluous.